# React: useQueries does not stringify nested query objects by default: use a custom stringifyQuery function

Tags: reactjs, react-router

I am trying to build up a URL to use as a target for a React NavLink (component borrowed from react-router-tutorial) but I'm struggling with the syntax for adding a query string to the "to" API property.

```
render: function(){
      urlParms = {show: "imagename"},

    return <NavLink to={{ pathname: 'image-viewer', query: { urlParms } }} className="nav-link">{this.props.data}</NavLink>
```

Using the above code the query shows up with as `image-viewer?urlParms%5Bobject+Object%5D` and Chrome's dev tool emits the above error for the link.

How do I write a "custom stringifyQuery function," and where would I deploy it?  If I put `query: { show: "imagename" }` in place of the above, it works just fine.

Answer (score 1):

You don't need the curly brackets around your `urlParms` object (btw, you should probably rename it, reads like a typo :).

What's happening now is that the `query` object that gets passed into the `NavLink`'s `to` prop looks like this:

```
{ urlParms: { show: "imagename" } }
```

What you need is just:

```
  return <NavLink to={{ pathname: 'image-viewer', query: urlParms }} className="nav-link">{this.props.data}</NavLink>
```

You could rename it to query and use the ES6 shorthand, since you seem to have that available:

```
  let query = { show: "imagename" }

  return <NavLink to={{ pathname: 'image-viewer', query }} className="nav-link">{this.props.data}</NavLink>
```